# Constant Variables in Java

Tags: java, static, instance

I'm creating some static objects inside a class like this. I want them to be constant but it seems that I did something wrong because all objects a b c are the same (their x are the same). Can anybody explain why?

```
public class Key {
private Note[] sequence;
private String name;

public Key() {
    this.sequence = Note.NOTES;
}

public Key(String name, Note[] notes) {
    this.sequence = Note.NOTES;
    this.name = name;
    for(int i = 0; i < this.sequence.length; i++){
        for(int j = 0; j < notes.length; j++){
            if(this.sequence[i].equals(notes[j])){
                this.sequence[i].setIntensity(0.6);
                break;
            }
            else this.sequence[i].setIntensity((double)0);
        }
    }
}

private static final Key C = new Key("C", new Note[]{Note.F2, Note.G2, Note.A2, Note.B2, Note.C3, Note.D3, Note.E3, Note.F3, Note.G3, Note.A3, Note.B3});
private static final Key CSharp = new Key("C#", new Note[]{Note.Fsharp2, Note.Gsharp2, Note.Asharp2, Note.C3, Note.Csharp3, Note.Dsharp3, Note.F3, Note.Fsharp3, Note.Gsharp3, Note.Asharp3});
private static final Key D = new Key("D", new Note[]{Note.Fsharp2, Note.G2, Note.A2, Note.B2, Note.Csharp3, Note.D3, Note.E3, Note.Fsharp3, Note.G3, Note.A3, Note.B3});
private static final Key EFlat = new Key("Eb", new Note[]{Note.F2, Note.G2, Note.Gsharp2, Note.Asharp2, Note.C3, Note.D3, Note.Dsharp3, Note.F3, Note.G3, Note.Gsharp3, Note.Asharp3});
private static final Key E = new Key("E", new Note[]{Note.Fsharp2, Note.Gsharp2, Note.A2, Note.B2, Note.Csharp3, Note.Dsharp3, Note.E3, Note.Fsharp3, Note.Gsharp3, Note.A3, Note.B3});
private static final Key F = new Key("F", new Note[]{Note.F2, Note.G2, Note.A2, Note.Asharp2, Note.C3, Note.D3, Note.E3, Note.F3, Note.G3, Note.A3, Note.Asharp3});
private static final Key FSharp = new Key("F#", new Note[]{Note.Fsharp2, Note.Gsharp2, Note.Asharp2, Note.B2, Note.Csharp3, Note.Dsharp3, Note.F3, Note.Fsharp3, Note.Gsharp3, Note.Asharp3, Note.B3});
private static final Key G = new Key("G", new Note[]{Note.Fsharp2, Note.G2, Note.A2, Note. B2, Note.C3, Note.D3, Note.E3, Note.Fsharp3, Note.G3, Note.A3, Note.B3});
private static final Key GSharp = new Key("G#", new Note[]{Note.F2, Note.G2, Note.Gsharp2, Note.Asharp2, Note.C3, Note.Csharp3, Note.Dsharp3, Note.F3, Note.G3, Note.Gsharp3, Note.Asharp3});
private static final Key A = new Key("A", new Note[]{Note.Fsharp2, Note.Gsharp2, Note.A2, Note.B2, Note.Csharp3, Note.Dsharp3, Note.E3, Note.Fsharp3, Note.Gsharp3, Note.A3, Note.B3});
private static final Key BFlat = new Key("Bb", new Note[]{Note.F2, Note.G2, Note.A2, Note.Asharp2, Note.C3, Note.D3, Note.Dsharp3, Note.F3, Note.G3, Note.A3, Note.Asharp3});
private static final Key B = new Key("B", new Note[]{Note.Fsharp2, Note.Gsharp2, Note.Asharp2, Note.B2, Note.Csharp3, Note.Dsharp3, Note.E3, Note.Fsharp3, Note.Gsharp3, Note.Asharp3, Note.B3});
}
```

Comment: No. The values of `x` will be different. Where have you tried printing those?

Comment: I did simplify of my code but I think it's quite the same. I don't know why but it makes all attributes become the same

Comment: Show us the complete code.

Comment: What is happening exactly?

Comment: the attributes sequence are the same for all static object. And they take the value of the last object (Key.B)

Answer (score 0):

Your code create different objects with different values, but *they are not constant*.

To create a **constant** you need to declare the variable as **`final`** and additionally you need to block any possibility to change it, making the object immutable. In this case, It can be done making **`final` all its fields**.
More generally to create an immutable class you need to follow some rules:

- Don't add any setter method
- Declare all fields final and private
- If a field is a mutable object create defensive copies of it for getter methods
- If a mutable object passed to the constructor must be assigned to a field create a defensive copy of it
- Don't allow subclasses to override methods.

If you like some additional informations on immutable objects I wrote an article on DZone that you can find at the following [link](https://dzone.com/articles/immutable-objects-in-java)

So for your code:

```
final Class A {
    final int x;

    public A(int x) {
        this.x = x;
    };

    private final static A a = new A(1);
    private final static A b = new A(2);
    private final static A c = new A(3);
}
```

---

To answer the last comment.

In your constructor you have:

```
public Key(String name, Note[] notes) {
    this.sequence = Note.NOTES;
    ...
}
```

it means that the value of `sequence` is common to all instances of `Key`. If you need different sequence values you need to do something like that (basically cloning the array Note.NOTES)

```
public Key(String name, Note[] notes) {
    this.sequence = Note.NOTES.clone();
    ...
}
```

Comment: It doesn't work. Actually, I tried to simplify my code. I will edit the post to my full code

Comment: Your previous example was working. Also this new code seems working, but I didn't runned it. Try to print the names. If they are different it works. Perhaps that your for loop will works differently as you like but the data are not the same, perhaps that they are equals (it means same values, not same references)

Comment: I tried create these objects separately (i.e I created only Key.C) and each of them gives different values. When I combine them altogether as above, their names are still different, only the sequence attributes become the same (and they take the value of the last object: Key.B)

Comment: So the problem is not that they are not different in terms of references. The problem is that they are equals in terms of values. So technically the problem is in your for loop (that wasn't present in the original question)

Comment: I printed out each object's sequence (which is an array). It shows @78308db1 for all objects. Does it mean it is the same reference? I'm too confusing